# How can I count the number of childrens (of a value) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following 3 table with nested data:

section table

```
id      title
1       s1
2       s2
3       s3
```

term table:

```
id      id_secion   
1       1
2       1
3       3
```

visit    table:

```
id      id_term
1       1
2       1
3       1
4       2
5       3
6       3
```

Which query or way do I need to go to get a result like this:

```
section     visit_count
1           4
2           0
3           2
```

data base export is:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `section` (
      `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
      `title` varchar(5) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;    

    INSERT INTO `section` (`id`, `title`) VALUES
    (1, 's1'),
    (2, 's2'),
    (3, 's3');

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `term` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `id_section` int(10) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    INSERT INTO `term` (`id`, `id_section`) VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 3);
```

visit table is:

Comment: Don´t know if you want to do it in pure mySQL or with PHP or something alike but this would be a job for a for-loop. And almost all languages have something like `count()`, this will help you, too.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT s.id AS section, COUNT(v.id_term) AS visit_count
FROM section s
LEFT JOIN term t
    ON s.id = t.id_section
LEFT JOIN visit v
    ON t.id = v.id_term
GROUP BY s.id
```

Follow the link below for a running demo:

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Change the first join to `LEFT` and use `COUNT(v.id_term )` to get `0` for section `2`.

Comment: @dnoeth thanks for the note and for not serial downvoting me.

Comment: That's what comments are for, adding minor improvements :) I hardly downvote, must be a *totally stupid* answer.

Comment: tanks, but your query get this result:

section     visit_count
1   6
2   1
3   2